# Why is gem telling me the current ruby version is 2.5.0 when it's not?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, ubuntu-16.04, rbenv

Context: I'm trying to install jekyll on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS so that I can work on a GitHub Pages site without having to deploy my changes to production every time I want to view them.

Here's the situation. When I run `sudo gem install jekyll`, it tells me to install google-protobuf. When I run `sudo gem install google-protobuf`, it tells me:

> google-protobuf requires Ruby version < 3.3.dev, >= 2.6. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.

Running `rbenv versions` shows me that there are two versions on my system

> system

> * 3.2.2 (set by /home/me/.rbenv/version)

I think `system` is the 2.5.0 version causing the problem, but running `ruby -v` outputs

> ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-linux]

and running `rbenv global` outputs

> 3.2.2

so it makes no sense to me that the system is still using 2.5.0. Can someone shed some light on what the fix is?

Comment: how about try `gem install jekyll` without sudo?

Comment: The idea behind tools like `rbenv` is that you don't need to use `sudo`, because your entire Ruby environment exists inside your own workspace as a sandbox. So I'd prioritise fixing the permissions issue (perhaps reinstalling ruby is the easiest way forward).

Comment: See the docs for [Installing Ruby gems](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-gems), in particular the warning starting with _"You should not use sudo to install gems."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing `rbenv` (but `rvm`, `asdf` and other similar tools), but as a Ruby Version manager, its job is to set up different/multiple Ruby environments with different gems installed for different users.

Since you call `sudo gem install ...` this will likely resolve to the global `gem` command available by default for a user with heightened priviliges (a *s*uper *u*ser). Most probably rbenv is not set up for this case, so that it falls back to the system-wide install `ruby` and `gem` commands, which seems to be Ruby 2.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Thus, try to run the command without `sudo`. If this fails, because it wants to install system-wide packages (libraries) resort to the rbenv documentation how to achieve this. It might give a list of commands to run (e.g. `sudo apt install libprotobuf`) or ask you for a password to do system modifications.